# What is client_id in the Stack Overflow OAuth API?

Tags: support, api

Where can I get client_id for Stack Overflow OAuth?

There is not much information about client_id [here](http://api.stackexchange.com/docs/authentication).

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The OAuth implementation requires registering the client application; that will generate a client id and secret id.

You can register the client application [here](https://stackapps.com/users/login?returnurl=/apps/oauth/register).